Enable connection to dApp in iframe
I have a payment widget that gets flagged by blowfish.xyz on non-whitelisted domains. I want to have my widget on multiple domains and the easiest way I have found to get around the domain restriction is to embed it via iframe.
But this limits the wallet adapter, since not all wallets are injecting themselves in child frames (Phantom doesn't, for example), so users can't connect their wallet.
Is it possible to manually inject Phantom into the iframe or create some sort of bridge between the frame and the parent? I haven't found any useful documentation for that.
How would this be implemented?

The basic steps are:

Set up wallet connection
Send Wallet Data to Iframe
Iframe: Listen for Messages from where you set up the wallet connection
Take into consideration security measures.

Set up wallet connection => (Hosting the iframe)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Parent Window</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/@solana/wallet- 
adapter/0.7.0/index.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="connect-wallet">Connect Wallet</button>
  <iframe id="dapp-iframe" src="https://your-dapp-url.com" style="width: 
  100%; height: 500px;"></iframe>

  <script>
    const { PhantomWalletAdapter } = window['@solana/wallet-adapter'];

    const wallet = new PhantomWalletAdapter();

    document.getElementById('connect-wallet').addEventListener('click', 
      async () => {
      try {
        await wallet.connect();
        const publicKey = wallet.publicKey.toString();
        console.log('Wallet connected:', publicKey);

        // Send the public key to the iframe
        const iframe = document.getElementById('dapp-iframe');
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({ type: 'WALLET_CONNECTED', 
       publicKey }, '*');
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Wallet connection failed:', err);
      }
    });

    // Listen for messages from the iframe if needed
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.origin !== 'https://your-dapp-url.com') return;

      console.log('Message from iframe:', event.data);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Iframe(dApp)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>dApp Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to My dApp</h1>
  <p id="wallet-info">Waiting for wallet connection...</p>

  <script>
    // Listen for messages from the parent window
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.data.type === 'WALLET_CONNECTED') {
        const publicKey = event.data.publicKey;
        document.getElementById('wallet-info').textContent = `Connected Wallet: ${publicKey}`;
      }
    });

    // Send messages to the parent window if needed
    window.parent.postMessage({ type: 'REQUEST_WALLET_CONNECTION' }, '*');
  </script>
</body>
</html>

The above is an example of how you can enable connection to dApp in iframe
You can read more about it here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src
Wallet Adapter => https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter

This still triggers the blowfish detection, because the connection is with the customer site, not my site where the widget dApp is actually running.
